# Many to many relationship hibernate with join on non-primary column hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have 4 tables -

1. ABU (columns- Key,Name) PK - Key
2. Project(columns- Key,Name) PK - Key
3. Journal Line(columns -Key,Name,LOB) PK- Key
4. ABU-LOB-Group(columns- ABU Key,Project Key,LOB,other columns)
      PK- ABU Key,Project Key,LOB

How can i create the pojo for last table (which is the join table) in Hibernate for this.

Comment: Read [that](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/) article.

Comment: @AfsunKhammadli: which article?

Comment: Click to the that

Comment: @AfsunKhammadli: But in my case join table doesn't have PK of Journal Line as join column,but it's joined by the column "LOB" of JournalLine which is not PK in that table